# PHP update statement with arrays

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, crud

Hi so I have an insert statement which works well, but need to create a separate update function which uses array keys and array values, which would be quite like the insert function but updates.

I have this for my insert

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO $tablename (".implode(",", array_keys($DATA).")" . " DATA ('".implode("','",array_values($DATA))."')";
connect()->query($sql);
```

This is what I have for my update so far but am stuck with it,

```
<?php
    function updatethis (array $id, array $values, $tablename)
    {
        $sql = "UPDATE $tablename SET (".implode(",", array_keys($DATA)).")" . " DATA ('".implode("','",array_values($DATA))."')";
        dbconnect()->query($sql); 
    } 
?>
```

Therefore I would like help on the update feature please .

So I am getting an error with the UPDATE syntax

This is the part i am struggling with, i cna give further explanation, but i must have put in the wrong syntax to update the database after i click edit on the index page it calls the function just the syntax is incorrect.

also its php to mySQL

index page for PHP updatee fucntion

```
 {
     $values = array();
     $idValues = array($idColumn => $id);
     foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
     {
         if(!empty($value) && ($value != "Submit"))
         {
             $values[$key] = $value;
         }
     } 
     $result = update($idValues, $values, $tableName);
 }
```

Edit: Error I am getting 
edit has not been successfull from below

```
  if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
                {
                    if($result>0)
                    {
                        echo 'Edit has been successful.  Return to index page';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo 'Edit has not been successful.';
                    }
                }
```

My code

```
function updateAll(array $id, array $values, $tablename)
{
    $sIDColumn  = key($id);
    $sIDValue   = current($id);
    $arrayValues = $values;
    array_walk($values, function(&$value, $key){
        $value = "{$key} = '{$value}'";
    });
    $sUpdate = implode(", ", array_values($values));
    $sql        = "UPDATE {$tablename} SET {$sUpdate} WHERE {$sIDColumn} = '{$sIDValue}'";


    connect()->query($sql);
}
```

My aim:  takes the input of the unique identifier of the row to be edited as an array of 1 then the value plus the name of the column representing the primary key, an array containing the values indexed by the column names as well as a string representing the table name useing array_keys and array_vaules like th insert but to update

Comment: What do you mean by "but am stuck with it"? Do you get an error(if so, show us the error) or do you get no error? What have you tried so far to solve this problem(this is so we can rule out some possibilities)? Edit the question with these question answered so we can help you better.

Comment: echo $sql please and u need where clause

Comment: @SugumarVenkatesan I just noticed that you beat me to it :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot UPDATE in the same way of INSERT. It should be like this :

```
$valueSets = array();
foreach($values as $key => $value) {
   $valueSets[] = $key . " = '" . $value . "'";
}

$conditionSets = array();
foreach($id as $key => $value) {
   $conditionSets[] = $key . " = '" . $value . "'";
}

$sql = "UPDATE $tablename SET ". join(",",$valueSets) . " WHERE " . join(" AND ", $conditionSets);
```

See details here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

Comment: Okay thanks, I have to use the function updatethis(array $id, array $values, $tablename) i will have a look at that

Comment: that kind of works but updates all of the fields not just 1

Comment: You want to update only one field? Which one field? How do you tell your function about that field?

Comment: Hi that's what i am struggling with, i have an idex page where i pefrom the data input, but with the above code it updates every row not just the single row

Comment: You need to add the where conditions in the last line of my code block

Comment: Thanks that is  what i am trying to work out but am finding it very hard, i guess its where id = $id so that it updates that row i am trying soemthing like this  $sql .= "WHERE id = {$id}";

Comment: Updated the answer again to reduce some more work for  you. Let me know if it helps. :)

Comment: Thanks very much that now updates 1 row, although it adds in a duplicate of the data and still throws update not successful error from my index page.

Comment: For data duplicacy you need to have unique constraints in Db and /or checking it with additional query before updating. For the error in your page. I see your function updatethis is not returning anything. Return true when query executes successfully.

Comment: Thanks again, i think i can solve the duplicates problem but am unsure where to i put it so it returns true, within the update function?

Comment: Great thanks that all works jut still getting duplicate, so  i edit 1 quantity under an order, this quantity then gets updated on all 3 orders which the customers has, is this to do with the update statement? Also i marked your answer thanks

Comment: Yes. You need to have specific order Id and that needs to be added in the condition so that it doesn't impact other orders.

Comment: Okay so say when I try to update i have UPDATE Order_Lines SET shipped = 'z' WHERE order_numb = '1' echoed from my sql statment, so do i need to change this database side or my update query?

Comment: The SQL looks fine. It should update only row with order_numb = 1. So, why do you think it updates other orders too?

Comment: Not sure i think it could be another problem, as i have other rows under order numb 1, thanks for your help though

Comment: If possible could you explain what is happing within your code, so I can add comments for future refence?

Comment: I didn't get your question. Can explain a bit more?

Comment: Sorry, just a brief outline on what's happing within that answer would be useful for me to comment into my programme,  especially with the join. part and the condition and value sets

Comment: Oh. First we are taking key and value for each of the items in values / id array and saving the statement (key = value) for each item in an array. Later we are joining those with comma for SET statements and with " AND" for WHERE statements.

Comment: Thanks again that's great i understand it better now, have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the pattern you are using is incorrect?

```
UPDATE table SET (rows) DATA ('values');
```

I think updates look more like this:

```
UPDATE table SET row1 = 'value1', row2 = 'value2';
```

In which case, this may be closer to what you are looking for.

```
function updatethis(array $id, array $values, $tablename)
{
    $sIDColumn  = key($id);
    $sIDValue   = current($id);
    $arrayValues = $values;
    array_walk($values, function(&$value, $key){
        $value = "{$key} = '{$value}'";
    });
    $sUpdate = implode(", ", array_values($values));
    $sql        = "UPDATE {$tablename} SET {$sUpdate} WHERE {$sIDColumn} = '{$sIDValue}'";
    dbconnect()->query($sql);
}
```

Using it, I get this query:

```
$testArray = array(
    "id" => 19,
    "username" => "test"
);
updatethis(array("id" => 9), $testArray, "users");

UPDATE users SET id = '19', username = 'test' WHERE id = '9'
```

I hope this at least helps but when it comes to databases, I only know MySQL and it is possible you are using another language.

Comment: Thanks I think this may be nearly there i just get an update function failed though i have added my index page to the top of the page for you to look into

Comment: I have updated my the function a little. If this still does not work, you will need to show us the exact error. If you do not know how to get that error then maybe tell us what database class you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try something like this : 
    $champs : Array of fields to update
    $valeurs : Array of value to update fields
    $conditions : Array of conditions

```
 protected function modify($table,$champs,$valeurs,$conditions){
            $Requete = "UPDATE ".$table." SET ";
            $nbChamps = count($champs);
            $nbValeurs = count($valeurs);
            if($nbChamps == $nbValeurs){
                for($i = 0; $i < $nbChamps ; $i++){
                    if($i < ($nbChamps - 1)){
                        if(is_numeric($valeurs[$i]))
                            $Requete = $Requete.$champs[$i]." = ".$valeurs[$i].",";
                        else
                            $Requete = $Requete.$champs[$i]." = '".$valeurs[$i]."',";
                    }
                    else
                        if(is_numeric($valeurs[$i]))
                            $Requete = $Requete.$champs[$i]." = ".$valeurs[$i]." ";
                        else
                            $Requete = $Requete.$champs[$i]." = '".$valeurs[$i]."' ";
                    }
                    $Requete = $Requete.$this->genereConditions($conditions);
                    $this->db->query($Requete);
                }
                else
                    throw new Exception("Le nombre de champs n'est pas identique au nombre de valeurs", 1); 
            }

    private function genereConditions($conditions){
            $condition = "WHERE ";
            for($i = 0 ; $i < count($conditions); $i++){
                if($i < (count($conditions)) - 1)
                    $condition = $condition.$conditions[$i]." AND ";
                else
                    $condition = $condition.$conditions[$i];
            }
            return $condition;
        }
```